# Complementation of deterministic Streett automata

Tags: automata, omega-automata

There are a lot of work about bounds on the complementation of Streett automata (see e.g. [this paper](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2011/3347/)). They talk about the general setting of nondeterministic Streett automata. But what about deterministic ones?

Streett automata are closed under determinisation although with an exponential blow-up. And complementation has an exponential complexity. So I would suppose that complementation of deterministic Streett automata would be simpler, maybe polynomial?

So, how do I complement **deterministic** Streett automata? Is the task computationally easy?

**Edit**: as far as I can tell, this question is equivalent to asking how to translate a deterministic Rabin automaton to an equivalent deterministic Streett automaton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This paper](https://faculty.runi.ac.il/udiboker/files/RabinVsStreett.pdf) gives an example of a deterministic Rabin automaton with $\mathcal{O}(n)$ states such that there is no nondeterministic (hence no deterministic) equivalent Streett automaton with less than $2^n$ states.

I guess there is no hope for a polynomial complementation, even if the Streett automaton is deterministic.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!